# How to go to other view controller when signed in from a google account ? (ios 10) if possible

Tags: ios10, google-signin

I have just learned to make a Google sign in button. Till now my app can login through the account but after login it redirects to the same page(Login page). I have googled everything but cant find a solution. How can I go to another view controller after signing from the google button?

Comment: Make another viewController where you wanna go. Now make a segue between both view controllers and give it an identifier. When get the login success from Google Signin then just call performSegueWithIdentifier("new identifer name of segue").

Comment: I did this: "SecondViewController" is the view controller I want to go to:

Answer (score 0):

I did this: "SecondViewController" is the view controller I want to go to:

```
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "idSegueContent" {
        secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController //Error is here
    }
}



public func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
    if (error) != nil {
        print(error)
    }
    else {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "idSegueContent", sender: self)
    }

}


func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWith user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
    if let err = error {
        print(error)
    }

    SecondViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    //Error is here too
}
```